# Elasticsearch & NEST with .NET - No Data Returned

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

Is there any debugging in NEST? I am wasting a lot of time without any error codes. I get no data returned but the data exists. The code is below -

```
        Uri node;
        ConnectionSettings settings;
        //ElasticClient client;

        node = new Uri("https://.......qb0x.com:30950");
       settings = new ConnectionSettings(node, defaultIndex: "soogrindex");
       var client = new ElasticClient(settings);


        SearchResults sr = new SearchResults();


        var searchDataResults = client.Search<SearchRow>(s=>s.AllIndices().AllTypes().Query(q=>q.Term(p=>p.partnumber, "*")));
```

Any ideas how to debug? It just returns nothing. A curl in ubuntu shows the data there. The .net is under windows.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your data? Just a sample json of your document. It seems that the query is wrong.

Comment: curl -XGET 'https://23ebed6f82b55e4b7cf1:f0680bcb86@3a7721e6.qb0x.com:30950/soogrindex/_search?q=partnumber:Test*'
{"took":5,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":4,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":390,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"soogrindex","_type":"searchrow","_id":"AVLFwBYtaAnYOoMODY4R","_score":1.0,"_source":{
  "partid": 2,
  "partnumber": "Test2"

Comment: could you try with this:         var searchDataResults = client.Search<SearchRow>(s=>s.AllIndices().AllTypes());

Comment: if it works then try with this:  var searchDataResults = client.Search<SearchRow>(s=>s.AllIndices().AllTypes().Query(q=>q.Term(p=>p.partnumber, "Test")));

Comment: Wow! The Alltypes returned 10 records.

Comment: The second query (p=>p.partnumber ... fails. Therefore the issue is related to the Query and Term verbs. There must be some kind of mapping issue. Can this be a DLL missing? BTW I used Test2 and also Test* and all failed. If we had some kind of response string with error codes that would really help. Is there anything like that in NEST?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103094/discussion-between-user2204027-and-alessandro-negro).

Comment: try in this way: var searchDataResults = client.Search<SearchRow>(s=>Query(q=>q.Term(p=>p.partn‌​umber, "Test")));

Comment: Term queries require a field that is not analyzed.  Terms are exact match filters and are evaluated before fuzzy matching.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html

Comment: what version of Elasticsearch and what version of NEST are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is about case, the data has "Test2" but the search fails to match on "Test2" but "test2" works. I have no idea why but there must be defaults set in ES.

Here is the corrected form -

```
 var searchDataResults = client.Search<SearchRow>(s=>s.AllIndices().AllTypes().Query(q=>q.Term(p=>p.partnumber, "test2")));
```

Comment: if you are indexing a `string` field using default configuration and mapping, then the value for the field will be analyzed by the `standard analyzer`, which, amongst other things, will lowercase any tokens generated from the input and store them in the inverted index. A `term` query's input does not undergo analysis at query time, so if you are expecting to find matches against a field that has been analyzed at index time, how it is analyzed needs to be taken into account. If you need to support full-text search *and* exact matching on a string field, you can map it as a `multi_field`